# Employee is a moderator?

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators, users-page

According to the moderators tab in /users [rossipedia](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/171886/) is a moderator, though he's described as a dev for Careers in his About Me.

> [image]

None of the other moderators that show up on this page are employees, Shog9, Anna (sorry everyone else I'm lazy) etc. are noticeably absent.

I'm assuming this is a bug therefore, though admittedly a tiny one.

Comment: This is also visible in the API, [his `is_employee` field is `false`](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users?inname=rossipedia&site=meta) ([compare with shog9](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users?inname=shog9&site=meta)).

Comment: Yup, bang on @Jeremy, someone updated the database wrong. I've written a few e-mails myself around how we were going to "review internal procedures" when this sort of thing happened... it translates into normal person as I'm going to tell the person who input the really important data to ensure they double check :-0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, got it.  He may remain in the moderators list for a time, but he will eventually fall out.

Comment: Fall out? So that's what you do with your ex mods? Drop them off a cliff? I feel bad for Kev now...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII No, we only do this to current employees. The job description only promises that they won't be poked with sharp sticks and conveniently doesn't mention cliff dropping.